# Updating a database on a Drupal site remotely?

Tags: mysql, database, drupal, database-connection

We have a PHP/MySQL site and we need to connect to a Drupal site and update certain tables/fields in its database.

1. Does Drupal have any mechanism that allows that?
2. If not, how can I connect to the Drupal site/ database and do that? Can Drupal allow a PHP script to listen for connections from our site and after authenticating it, update the local database?
3. Is it safe / secure / reliable to do a connect to the MySQL database running on the Drupal site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very doable. Your hosting provider probably gives you some way to talk to the database directly (shell access or phpMyAdmin, for example).

If you want something better than just raw SQL, though, you might consider building a web service. See the [drupal services module](http://drupal.org/project/services).

Comment: Thanks @tangentstorm. We're planning to give away modules that can be integrated into Drupal sites, so I think the Drupal services module might be the right idea for us to build on/use.

Answer (score 0):

using phpmyadmin you can do safe mysql connection
http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/index.php

Comment: anth - I dont think I understand - how will phpmyadmin help here? I need to provide access to the drupal database from my php/mysql website.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to code against the database schema directly if you can avoid it. Having a third party editing Drupal's database is mostly a bad idea (for too many reasons). Go through the appropriate API or use the services module as @tangentstorm suggested.